# Willpower - do kills increase it?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I have long lost hope to get the hard numbers on how willpower works, just kinda accepted that it grows with levels and you lose it when critically wounded, and each class gains slightly different amounts.

But today I noticed I have two snipers that are identical in every way, except that one of them

- has 2 more kills
- has 2 more willpower

(I have not yet researched Iron Will, and both ladies are drafted the usual way, not as mission rewards).

Really? Does every kill actually increases willpower by 1? If not, what's going on here?!

Screenshots:

[First gal, with 43 will](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECrHl.jpg)

[Second gal, with 45 will](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxsV1.jpg)

Comment: Well, yes it is now, wasn't answered when I was asking =)

Comment: Just because a question isn't answered doesn't mean it's fine to ask a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to actually find the answer. But there's no need to lecture - I did my searching, didn't find anything helpful - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bxcom-enemy-unknown%5D+willpower . Now it has your question, that actually does have an answer (which it didn't then), but it still is at the very end. Maybe if you changed the title to something shorter like "Willpower gain mechanics" it will be easier to find.

Comment: spartacus' answer answers your question perfectly - will gain is random, i.e. not dependant on the number of kills (not that it matters, asking a duplicate question is not the correct thing to do if your question has already been asked but hasn't received an answer you like). Considering you said you had already found that question, I'd say it's easy enough to find.